# Calculate number of days between 2 dates Unix Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to calculate number of days between two dates in the unix shell .
I tried to do a minus calculation but it dosen’t work .
This is my script

```
VAR1=$1
VAR2=$2
v_date_deb=`echo ${VAR1#*=}`
v_date_fin=`echo ${VAR2#*=}`

dif = ($v_date_deb - $v_date_fin)
echo dif

if [ "$v_date_deb" = "" ]
then
  echo "Il faut saisir la date debut.."
  exit
fi

if [ "$v_date_fin" = "" ]
then
  echo "Il faut saisir la date fin.."
  exit
fi
```

Comment: What is your input? Please make it a [mre].

Comment: The input its the Var1 and var2 that the user enter as a date ( Exp 11-09-2022)

Comment: Unless you deliberately want to use the shell for mangling whitespace, there is no need for `$(echo ...)` (ever).  Just use `v_date_deb=${VAR1#*=}`. And don't name your variables all caps.  THERE'S NO NEED TO SHOUT

Comment: `it doesn't work` doesn't tell us what the issue is; please update the question to show a sample invocation of your script, the (wrong) output generated by your script, a description of what `it doesn't work` means (error? wrong answer? something else?) and the (correct) expected output

Answer (score 1):

One attempt (but shot in the dark, since we don't know what is in your `VAR1` variables)

```bash
ts1=$(date -d "${VAR1#*=}" +"%s")
ts2=$(date -d "${VAR2#*=}" +"%s")
dt=$(( (ts2 - ts1) / 86400 ))
```

Note the remark from William Pursell above: this solution is dependent on your "date" version. Date is not a built-in command from bash. And, particularly, the `-d` option (that allows to use the date specified instead of the current date that `date` is supposed to use otherwise, when used in "print the date" mode) is not common to all "date".

Comment: Note that this is highly dependent on the version of `date`, as `-d` is not standard.  (This does not work in bsd date commonly available on macOS, where you might try `date -jf '%d/%m/%Y' "${1#*=}" +%s` ). But converting to epoch time is the correct approach.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks. I add the remark to the answer (I started writing my answer with the intention of saying it, and then I forget by the end of the, only 4-lines long tho, post. But indeed. I do own a computer on which this doesn't work)